# gradle does not import local java libraries

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following folder structure:

-bin

-build/build.gradle (the gradle script)

-lib/[*.jar] (libraries that the project is using)

-src/folder/folder/[*.java] (project's source code)

The following content for the build.gradle script:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
}

buildDir = new File('../bin') 
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 

sourceSets { 
    main { 
        java { 
            allJava.srcDirs = [ '../src/folder/folder/ '] 
            compileClasspath = fileTree('../bin') 
        } 
    } 
} 

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs '../lib'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree('../lib')
}

tasks.register('javac', JavaCompile) { 
    println 'Call javac' 
    source.forEach { e -> println e} 

    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath 
    destinationDirectory = file('../bin') 
    source sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs 
    includes.add('*.java') 
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
}
```

When running `gradle javac`  I got the error:  `error: cannot find symbol import com...`

The documentations clearly says:

```
dependencies {
.
.
.
    //putting all jars from 'libs' onto compile classpath
    implementation fileTree('libs')
}
```

I'm using Gradle 7.3.1

Comment: Safe to assume your `folder/folder` is actually `com/.../` that matches your `import` statements? From which directory do you run Gradle? Does it interpret the relative path relative to the current directory or to `build.gradle`? If you run from the top directory, try removing the `../` from paths like `implementation fileTree('../lib')`.

Comment: Yes, those paths are only for example. I tried with absolut and relative paths but with no success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to give you some general advice first.
I can strongly recommend using the Kotlin DSL instead of the Groovy DSL.
You instantly get strongly typed code in the build scripts and much better IDE support.

Also you should imho consider changing your project layout to be more like most other Java projects out there and especially not use a `libs` directory, but use normal dependencies in a repository where transitive dependencies are then handled automatically and so on.

But to answer your actual question, this is the complete build script in Groovy DSL that you want:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

buildDir = '../bin'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(8))
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['../src/folder/folder']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree('../lib')
}
```

And this is the matching Kotlin DSL version:

```
plugins {
    java
}

setBuildDir("../bin")

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(8))
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            setSrcDirs(listOf("../src/folder/folder"))
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree("../lib"))
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing the layout is not an option... I will try to switch to kotlin though. One thing I must point out: setting the `JavaLanguageVersion` to 8 did not worked. I had to set `options.release = 8` property inside the `JavaCompile` task. I think the `srcDirs` method from `java sourceSets` only looks one level, but I have 3 levels of folders so I had to include them all. Is there a function that looks for java files no matter how nested they are?

Comment: You should not set `options.release`, the toolchain setting should work. If it is not, something is very strange or missing. `srcDir`s should be set to the directories where the package structure starts. But you have a turing-complete language available, so if you don't want to do it manually, just list the directory and automatically add all subdirectories as `srcDir`.